# How to add two a5 sheets on A4 sheet with itext5

Tags: java, printing, itext

I need a pdf file which has a two A5 on A4.

Like this, after i print this A4, so how to do it?

[image]

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
    //Original page
    PdfPage origPage = sourcePdf.getPage(1);
    com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();
    PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
    //N-up page
    PageSize nUpPageSize = PageSize.A4.rotate();
    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(nUpPageSize);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
            nUpPageSize.getWidth() / orig.getWidth() / 2f,
            nUpPageSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight() / 2f);
    canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
    //Add pages to N-up page
    canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, orig.getHeight());
    canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, orig.getWidth(), orig.getHeight());
    // close the documents
    pdf.close();
    sourcePdf.close();
```

Comment: Are you creating the PDF from scratch. Or do you already have the A5 PDF that you want to put on an A4 sheet twice? What have you tried? Did you read the tutorial where you can find examples that do almost exactly what you want? https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents If you get down-votes on this questions, these could be the reasons: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I create a pdf (itext5) file like template, after i have to enter data in these two pdf a5, and after that i will print two a5 on one a4

Comment: (1.) iText 5 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to iText 7 if you want me to help. (2.) If you want help from someone who still answers iText 5 questions, you will need to post some code. Without code, no one can tell you what you are doing wrong. (For instance: you forgot to rotate the A5 pages and you used the wrong scaling. In short: your problem is a Math problem, not an iText problem.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I added some code, please help me

Comment: What happens if you change `orig.getHeight()` to `0` in the lines where you do `canvas.addXObject()`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  http://rgho.st/7rpCVQwFW

Comment: OK, you're very close, now replace `nUpPageSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight() / 2f` with `nUpPageSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight()`, and show the result. (Actually, the Math isn't correct, but this should do the trick.)

Comment: I assume that this solved your problem.